# Is this really enough to prove that we are dealing with an elementary embedding?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, model-theory

(Sorry for the weak title of my question. I really don't know how to formulate my question properly in short.)

On pages 101,102 of [A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic (2nd
edition)](https://knightscholar.geneseo.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1005&context=geneseo-authors) in exercise 9 the reader is asked to prove the following:

> Let $L$ be some language and let $\mathfrak{A}$ be an $L$-structure
> with domain $A$. Then let $L\left(A\right)=L\cup\left\{ \overline{a}\mid a\in A\right\} $
> and let $\overline{\mathfrak{A}}$ denote the extension of $\mathfrak{A}$
> having again $A$ as domain and with $\overline{a}^{\overline{\mathfrak{A}}}=a$
> for every $a\in A$.

> Further let it be that $\overline{\mathfrak{B}}$ denotes an $L\left(A\right)$-structure
> with domain $B$ and satisfies: $\overline{\mathfrak{A}}\vDash\phi\implies\mathfrak{\overline{B}}\vDash\phi$
> for every $L\left(A\right)$-formula $\phi$.

> Then $\mathfrak{A}$ is isomorphic to an elementary substructure of
> $\mathfrak{B}$ where $\mathfrak{B}$ denotes the reduct $\overline{\mathfrak{B}}\upharpoonright L$.

Hinted is that the function $h:A\to B$ prescribed
by $a\mapsto\overline{a}^{\mathfrak{B}}$ could be used for that. I expect a typo there and that they actually mean $a\mapsto\overline{a}^{\overline{\mathfrak{B}}}$ because $\overline{a}$ has no interpretation in $\mathfrak{B}$.

On the pages 313,314 and 315 (two and a half pages!) a rather extensive answer is
given.

I found an alternative answer myself that is surprisingly (hence also "suspicuously") simple and
much shorter *which makes me worry that I overlooked things*.

Essential for my solution is the observation that for a formula $\phi=\phi\left(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}\right)$
and elements $a_{1},\dots,a_{n}\in A$ the following statements are
equivalent:

1. $\overline{\mathfrak{A}}\vDash\phi\left[a_{1},\dots,a_{n}\right]$
2. $\overline{\mathfrak{A}}\vDash\phi\left(\bar{a}_{1},\dots,\bar{a}_{n}\right)$
3. $\overline{\mathfrak{B}}\vDash\phi\left(\bar{a}_{1},\dots,\bar{a}_{n}\right)$
4. $\overline{\mathfrak{B}}\vDash\phi\left[h\left(a_{1}\right),\dots,h\left(a_{n}\right)\right]$

The equivalence of 1) and 2) rests on $a^{\overline{\mathfrak{A}}}=a$ for every $a\in A$.

The equivalence of 3) and 4) rests on $a^{\overline{\mathfrak{B}}}=h(a)$ for every $a\in A$.

The implication 2)$\implies$ 3) is direct
and because $\phi\left(\bar{a}_{1},\dots,\bar{a}_{n}\right)$ is a
sentence we can conclude that also 3)$\implies$ 2).

This means that for every $L$-formula $\phi$ and every
$\overline{\mathfrak{A}}$-assignment $s$ we have: $$\overline{\mathfrak{A}}\vDash\phi\left[s\right]\iff\overline{\mathfrak{B}}\vDash\phi\left[h\circ s\right]$$
which means exactly that $h:\overline{\mathfrak{A}}\to\overline{\mathfrak{B}}$
is an elementary embedding.

This on its turn implies that also $h:\mathfrak{A}\to\mathfrak{B}=\overline{\mathfrak{B}}\upharpoonright L$
is an elementary embedding so that $h$ can be recognized as an isomorphism $\mathfrak{A}\to h(\mathfrak{A})$ where $h(\mathfrak{A})$ is an elementary substructure of $\mathfrak{B}$.

---

My question:

> Would you be so kind please to check me on mistakes?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you write is correct.

Comment: @PrimoPetri I am glad to hear that. Thank you for looking at it and your welcome confirmation.

Comment: I don't understand "because $\phi(\bar a_1,\dots,\bar a_n)$ is a sentence, we can conclude that also 3) $\implies$ 2)." It's true that 3) $\implies$ 2), but the proof I see for that is to apply 2) $\implies$ 3) to $\neg\phi$ in place of $\phi$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I did not mention that explicitly but it is the proof you sketch that I had in mind for this. On page 96 there is proposition 3.4.5. that corresponds with it. Also we can think in terms of ultrafilters. If $U$ and $V$ are ultrafilters (on the algebra of $L(A)$-sentences) with $U\subseteq V$ then we are allowed to conclude that $U=V$. It might have been better to mention it.